# Force windows authentication IID

Tags: asp.net, security

I am having an authentication issue with an ASP.net application.  This was working and now for some reason has stopped.  I have a web form that connects to a SQL database for simple data entry.  I am trying to capture the user name and time in the background to include with the entry.  I have the following code in the web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

This is within the system.web grouping.

I have following routine set in the .cs file for the web form:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);database=InvoiceSHC;Trusted_Connection=Yes"))
    {

        // Get the UserId of the logged in user 

        string UserName = "";
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
       }
        else
       {
           UserName = "UnauthenticatedUser";
       } 


        string Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        //Not sure why you need a SqlDataAdapter unused here.
        //SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("UpdateSHCInvoice", con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateSHCInvoice", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ref", dlRef.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhaseName", dlPhase.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageType", dlPageType.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page", tbPage.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent", dlPercent.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChngType", dlChngType.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timestamp",Timestamp);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Within IIS I have disabled anonymous authentication.  I have enabled asp.net Impersonation and Windows Authentication.

When I first set this up, I was getting a domain and id for the user.  Now I do not get prompted for the user name and password when I go to the site.  This authentication stuff is a real pain.

I am using Firefox as the browser.  I have also tried this on Safari with the same results.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added an authorization section to your web.config file?

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

What this does is tell the web server that you want to allow any authenticated users (`users="*"`) and deny any anonymous users (`users="?"`) at the root level and subsequently, across your entire site.

If you need different authorization settings for different pages or folders, you can use the `location` element:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="members">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
                <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="AnonymousPage.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

This can be added into your root web.config file, it can also be added in the same way as the first example in a web.config file inside the desired folder.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and have the same results.  When I go to the page, I am not prompted to give my user name and password.  This is the behavior I am trying to achieve.  In other words, whenever the user goes to the web page, they need to be prompted for their login and password.

Comment: I made a typo in the code, should have been a * not an 8.. Although I'm assuming you spotted that. Do you require ASP.Net impersonation? Perhaps disabling that might change something?

Comment: I caught the typo.  I have disabled the asp.net impersonation.  I am just not getting the request to provide a login and password when I go to the site.  I have tried multiple combinations of the Windows Authentication and Basic Authentication but without success.  When I run the application from Visual Web Developer(Windows2008Server,IE browser) I somehow authenticate without entering a login and password.  When I run it on my local machine (Max OS, Firefox browser) I get nothing.  This is sooooo confusing.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know what to suggest, usually when I have only Windows authentication enabled on the IIS site and these config settings it just works =\

Comment: I had a couple of issues going on at the same time.  First I had my web site in two different folders which was very confusing as to how it happened in the first place.  I found this when I was looking at the app pool and saw two sites for the app pool I was using.  Second, I failed to reestablish the default start page.  Since I only have one page, it should be simple, but IIS does not assume anything and I did not tell it what my default page was so I would get a 401 or 404 error.  Thanks to everyone who contributed.